# Implementing an interface while extending an abstract class that implements some of the interface methods

Tags: oop, design-patterns, software-design

Let's say we have the following(just writing some loose pseudocode I hope that is ok):

```
abstract class AbstractClass {
           public method1(): void {
           //does something
           };
             
           public abstract method2() : void;
}

interface ExampleInterface {
     method1() : void;
     method2() : void;
     method3() : void;
}

class ExampleClass extends AbstractClass, implements ExampleInterface {
     public method2() : void {
     // does something 
     };
     public method3() : void {
     // does something
     }
}
```

It feels a little weird to extend a class that partially implements the interface. Is this a code smell for bad design or is it reasonable to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> It feels a little weird to extend a class that partially implements the interface. Is this a code smell for bad design or is it reasonable to do this?

Strictly speaking `AbstractClass` does not actually "partially implement `ExampleInterface`", it just has methods with names matching signatures of the interface ones (which can be used as methods implementing the interface).

> Is this a code smell for bad design or is it reasonable to do this?

Usually answer for such questions is - "it depends".  One potential issue here is the signature changes of interface or abstract class methods. Personally I would look into changing the `AbstractClass` to actually partially implement the interface (if the language allows it):

```
abstract class AbstractClass implements ExampleInterface  {
    public void method1() {
        //does something
    };
}
```

Another approach worth considering is [composition over inheritance](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/composition-vs-inheritance) - there is a strong argument in developer community for "inheritance is never a solution", while I do not completely agree with it, it's quite useful to remember about it in a lot of cases.